# Adding File To resourse folder dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I dynamically(by code) add Images to my resource folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible because the code will be executed on your iPhone. So all resources should already be there (on device). And resources are not put in a bundle by iPhone. So when you will run your app on iPhone (or any other iOS device) your bundle will be already packed and all the resources were not put into it will stay on your computer and will be not accessible.

Possibly you want to add resources to your project as folder references, not as groups. If you will add a folder reference to your project such way and will update some files in this folder or add new files they will be automatically added to your project by xcode

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do that you think this is the solution?  Add to your own resource folder? (i.e., to the app that is running's own resource folder?).  Why would you want to do this.  You can add it dynamically to the view when it is displayed, set a user default value if you need to flag the yes/no of adding it if you need to set that but display it at some other time.  Really though, we need to understand the goal of what you are doing.

Reading the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12:

> Application_Home/AppName.app - 
>   This is the bundle directory containing the application itself. Do not write anything to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your application from launching again.
>   In iOS 2.1 and later, the contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes. However, iTunes does perform an initial sync of any applications purchased from the App Store."

SO even if you wrote code to do this, it likely will keep your app from subsequently launching if the documentation is to be believed.  Use the Documents folder, or somewhere in the Library folder or one of the other locations indicated.  Then use NSBundle's methods to find the folder for fetching the images later.

Comment: Are you adding them at runtime? (like downloading them from the net?)